# how do i make highstock last point until the middle of the graph?

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to make highstock graph last point reach until the middle when it dynamically added.

i tried to search how to expand the xAxis more 40 min+ but can't find anything.

thank's
Tamir.

Comment: You want half the chart to be empty?

Comment: Could you explain how it should look like or supply a mockup ?